# Resizeable Number Pyramid Panel with Swing

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, stringbuilder

I am trying to create a resizable window with Swing and AWT components which displays numbers in a pyramid fashion depending on what the frame is sized to but I have no idea really where to start. I am not sure if I am supposed to use JLabel or StringBuilder.  If it can be done without using action listeners, that would be preferred.  I need some assistance.

Answer (score 4):

I would simply create a dedicated panel and override the method paintComponent. Then using the FontMetrics and the size of that panel, I would iterate and fill the panel with a pyramid.

Here is an example of what I am mentionning (although there is still a problem when the number of digits increases, but I will let you fix this problem):

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestPyramid {

    private static class PyramidPanel extends JPanel {
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setFont(new Font("Courier", Font.PLAIN, 11));
            FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
            fm.getHeight();
            int i = 0;
            int y = 0;
            int n = 1;
            while (y + fm.getHeight() < getHeight()) {
                int x = getWidth() / 2;
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int j = 0; j < 2 * i + 1; j++) {
                    String v = String.valueOf(n++);
                    sb.append(v);
                    for (int fill = 0; fill < 4 - v.length(); fill++)
                        sb.append(" ");
                }
                String text = sb.toString();
                int stringWidth = fm.stringWidth(text);
                if (stringWidth > getWidth()) {
                    break;
                }
                x -= stringWidth / 2;
                y += fm.getHeight();
                g.drawString(text, x, y);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(TestPyramid.class.getSimpleName());
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new PyramidPanel());
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestPyramid().initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have "fixed" the number of digits issue

Comment: @brimborium there is still a glitch when the number of digits increases (it is particularly obvious when it goes over 100). And it is not a good idea to use string concatenation within a loop, it should rather reuse the existing StringBuilder. Also, could you please not rename my SSCCE class? I find it a lot more useful to have a meaningful classname than just "Main". This also allows me to copy/paste the code without erasing previous SSCCE. Thanks

Comment: Ok, I fixed the class rename and it uses the `StringBuilder` now for concatenation. But yes, once the values go over 1k, the issue still remains. It would be possible to estimate how many numbers can be displayed and from that calculate the maximal string width. I just applied a simple fix with a constant width per number. If OP wants it to be dynamic, he can work from your code.

Comment: Oh and if you don't like the changes, feel free to roll back the edit. :) (or tell me and I'll do it)

Comment: @brimborium thanks for your contribution and for naming the class back to its original name (if you use eclipse you can paste directly the Java code within a Java project and it will create the appropriate file automatically). For the rollback, unless it is really an insult to my work, I don't like to do that because it looks like I just destroy a cnotribution while I prefer to improve it; I find that friendlier. Cheers!

Comment: Oh, thanks for the paste hint, I didn't know that. Very handy. @rollback: Yes, sure. But if the change is not improving your answer, a rollback is a good option, whether it's friendly or not towards the editor. ;)